# ghostscript command line arguments output file name change

Tags: printing, ghostscript

I am using ghostscript to print a pdf by command line arguments in c#. but it shows the printed document's name as ghostScript output. I want to change it to a custom name(as letter's name). I know in command line parameters, it does not allow to change it. please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I really don't understand what you're asking. You specify where Ghostscript should write it's output using the "-o" or "-sOutputfile=" command line parameters. The name of the input file does not influence the output file.

*Unless* you are using something like ps2pdf.....

If you can clarify what you are trying to do, I or someone else can likely help.

Chris